# Ho to get last event using rest url from Elastic search particular index using timestamp inbuilt column?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, elasticsearch

From angular app i want call a rest service that returns latest event of a particular index and can anyone please provide me constructed url ?

Comment: Please improve your question as it does not make a lot os sense. At least not to me.

Answer (score 0):

In the event post long number of date as field and from angular app use [current date in long] and [current date in long-someseconds] and give the both value in the rest query against new field

Comment: Is this supposed to answer something? I think you need to use a site where you can use your native language